# Monitoring multiple remote Dell PowerEdge servers

Tags: monitoring, dell, dell-poweredge

We have a number of remote PowerEdge servers that we would like to monitor for hardware issues.  Some of the servers are accessible by VPN while others are only accessible over the internet behind a NAT device.  What is the best way to monitor these servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you would use a combination of Dell OpenManage Server Administrator on the managed systems and Dell IT Assistant or Dell Management Console on the management system. Accessing the managed systems via a VPN connection should be no problem but accessing them across the internet will require you to open some ports on the firewall on the managed systems end. You can get more information here:

http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/dcsm-dell-consoles.aspx?c=us&cs=555&l=en&s=biz&redirect=1

Answer (score 0):

If you mean monitoring the hardware then you can more then likely use the Dell OpenManage alerts.  If you have a smtp server available at the site then setup the Dell OpenMange alerting to pass the messages off to smtp.  You will then get a mail message from the dell server describing the alarm/alert/hardware problem.

Also as noted above you can possibly use IT Assistant or the new DMC (Dell Management Console).